# Incorrect syntax near 'unsigned' Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, syntax, unsigned

Im having an error with this query, I'm using a the latest SQL server and management studio

See the query below

```
CREATE TABLE messages_server (
Id int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
SentTime datetime,
MessageRead BIT,
Content varchar(8000),
MessageCategory varchar(255),
MessageUser varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)
```

Comment: I don't think `UNSIGNED` is a valid type in SQL Server.

Comment: There is no unsigned property in SQL Server, nor is `AUTO_INCREMENT` a T-SQL operator (it uses `IDENTITY`). *All* numerical data types, with the exception of `tinyint`, are signed data types in SQL Server.

Comment: The OP is trying to run a MySQL script in SQL Server. Closing as "typo".

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft SQL Server does not support unsigned integer types, it also doesn't support the keyword AUTO_INCREMENT. It looks like you have generated a script from another DB engine and tried to run it on SQL Server. The corrected script below should run.

```
CREATE TABLE messages_server (
Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
SentTime datetime,
MessageRead BIT,
Content varchar(8000),
MessageCategory varchar(255),
MessageUser varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)
```

Comment: *"it should run"* It won't due to the `AUTO_INCREMENT`, as already mentioned in the comments.

Comment: It's `IDENTITY [(<Seed Value>, <Increment Value>)]` @TheImpaler . There's no `GENERATED BY DEFAULT` clause.

Comment: I should know better than to quickly dash off an answer on this site, there are comments pointing out your error within 30 seconds lol.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, firstly SQL Server doesn't support choice of signing of data types; all numerical data types are signed data types with the exception of `tinyint` which is an unsigned 1-byte integer. If you want to ensure that a column is always a positive value use a `CHECK` `CONSTRAINT`.

T-SQL also doesn't use `AUTO_INCREMENT` it uses `IDENTITY`.

As such, you likely want something like this. Note I also name your primary key, as naming your `CONSTRAINT`s is important:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.messages_server (Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
                                  SentTime datetime,
                                  MessageRead bit, --Should this be NULLable?
                                  Content varchar(8000),
                                  MessageCategory varchar(255),
                                  MessageUser varchar(255),
                                  CONSTRAINT PK_messages_server PRIMARY KEY (Id),
                                  CONSTRAINT chk_id_signed CHECK (Id >= 0));
```